# Sorting files from a folder

Tags: php, sorting

I am using the below php codes to get all files from a folder `logfiles_patient`

```
$path = "logfiles_patient/";
    // Open the folder
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");
    // Loop through the files
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
    {
        if(($file!='.')&&($file!='..'))
        {
    echo "<a target='_blank' href='log_Patient_download.php?filename=$file'>$file</a>";
        }
    }
    // Close
    closedir($dir_handle);
```

and the output echoed is

```
March 19, 2014.txt
March 20, 2014.txt
March 21, 2014.txt
```

I want to rearrange the the output as

```
March 21, 2014.txt
March 20, 2014.txt
March 19, 2014.txt
```

Comment: Does the file name correspond with the file creation date?

Comment: Yes.Filename is the date of creation of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store temporarily your `$file var` in an `array`, and applying [sorting functions](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/array.sorting.php) after the `while` loop.

Like this:

```
$array = array();    

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))
{
     if(($file!='.')&&($file!='..'))
          $array[] = $file;
}

$array = arsort($array);

foreach($array as $file)
    echo "<a target='_blank' href='log_Patient_download.php?filename=$file'>$file</a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try something like this:

```
$files = glob('logfiles_patient/*');
if(is_array($files)){
    foreach ($files as $file){
        $coll[basename($file)] = filemtime($file);
    }
    asort($coll);
    $files = array_keys($coll);
}
```

Bear in mind that if `glob()` encounters an error, it will return `false`.